# Main verb missing

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

***Wuthering Heights is the name of Mr. Heathcliff’s dwelling. ‘Wuthering’ being a significant provincial adjective, descriptive of the atmospheric tumult to which its station is exposed in stormy weather.***

```
   —Wuthering heights
```

There is no main verb in the second sentence. How? Is it just to suit the author's will or in 18th-19th century it was not wrong to do so?

Comment: It would be more usual _either_ to make it all one sentence _or_ to change _being_ to _is_.

Answer (score 1):

Emily Brontë is attempting to simulate the style of a personal diary (as written by Lockwood).  This style looks like a set of personal notes that Lockwood is writing down rather than carefully structured prose. As you note, it would be "correct" to make it all one sentence, or rephrase, but "correct" is not Brontë's main aim.

However this is straying into literary analysis, rather than English Learning.